# Linux Bash Shell read with tab support (\t)

Tags: bash, read

There is `\t` option for horizontal tab in `echo`

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo hello
hello
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ echo -e '\thello'
    hello
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is there any similar option in `read`?

```
wolf@linux:~$ read -p 'hello '
hello wolf
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ read -p '\thello '
\thello wolf
wolf@linux:~$
```

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ read -p '\thello ' <- need something to produce something like tab or `\t` in `echo`
    hello wolf
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the ksh93-style `$'...'` form of quotes that understand those escape sequences:

```
IFS= read -r -p $'\thello ' var
```

(the `IFS=` and `-r` are not relevant, I'm just adding them here as calling `read` without them rarely makes sense).

Note that `-p` is not a standard `sh` function. In ksh/zsh, `-p` is to read from the co-process and prompts are specified with `read 'var?Prompt: '`. It's unfortunate that `bash` chose to introduce an incompatible API here. You don't have to use `-p` though, you can just do portably:

```
printf >&2 '\thello '
IFS= read -r var
```

`printf` does recognise those escape sequences in its format argument, and arguments for `%b` specifiers. Whether `echo` recognises them (or accepts a `-e` option to recognise them) depends on the implementation and for many implementations (including `bash`'s builtin) on build time and runtime settings, so is [best avoided](/q/65803).

Answer (score 1):

You could always simply add 8 spaces:

```
read -p '        hello '
```

But yes, you can also get an actual tab character:

```
read -p $'\t''hello '
```

Or

```
read -p "$(echo -e '\thello ')"
```

Or

```
read -p "$(printf '\thello ')"
```

Comment: Why `4` spaces? TAB stops are generally 8 columns apart in terminals.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas because that's the OP had.

Comment: It looks more like it's how stackexchange renders tabs. It's actually really annoying as most terminals and web browsers do render them 8 columns apart, so when you're copy pasting a TAB from a terminal to the editing textarea when writing a SE post, it's fine, but when you post the article, the formatting is mangled.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas eh, either way, the point was just that you can add N spaces and might not need a tab, specifically. I'm happy to change it to 8, if you prefer.